# Unable to manually resize absolute value bars

Tags: mathtools

I would like to manually adjust the size of my absolute value bars so I don't end up with expressions that look like this:

[image]

As per what I've read around here, I tried to include `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}` in my preamble. But this results in the following error:

```
Command \abs already defined.
```

Indeed, `\abs` does work for me (since I have included the `mathtools` package in my preamble); but anytime I try to size these things manually by including, e.g., `\bigg` I get an error claiming that 'Argument of \bBigg@ has an extra }' which does not make any sense.

For example, the code that produced the above expression is as follows:

```
\int_{\O}\abs{f(Z_n) - f(Z_0) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Af(Z_k)} \dif \P
```

But, if I try

```
\int_{\O}\abs[\bigg]{f(Z_n) - f(Z_0) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Af(Z_k)} \dif \P
```

I am presented with the error described above.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what the problem is here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To answer the question, we need more information; could you make an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) reproducing the problem? If `\abs` is already defined, it must be defined somewhere!

Comment: My hunch is that you're loading some package that defines both `\abs` and `\dif`. Have you tried issuing the instruction `\let\abs\relax` before `\DeclarePairedDelimiter...`?

Comment: @Mico That did it. Thank you!